# É vs. E in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, primary-key

MySQL thinks É and E are the same and thus throw an exception saying **Duplicate entry 'CLEME' for key 'PRIMARY'**

MySQL is 5.1.30 and the table uses utf8-unicode-ci and the field is defined as follows:

**`search_key` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,**

Is there a way to let this field know they are not the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the character set of the field to UTF-8 as well. Also, set the connection character set to UTF-8 when you do the insert.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. However, I tried jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tablename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8 and changed field charset to utf8-general-ci but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: `utf8-general-ci` is a collation charset - which dictates character ordinality. Use just `utf8` for the charset.