# MySQL Not Distinguishing Between 'e' and 'é' (using JDBC)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, primary-key

I'm using a UTF-8 collated database, which is a character set that should be able to distinguish between 'e' and 'é'...  Unfortunately issuing the following 2 inserts from the MySQL Workbench and/or JDBC directly

```
INSERT INTO `ucap_i10_13_02_27$12_48_41`.`attributes` (`attribute`, `intvalue`) VALUES ('brown-séquard', 1);


INSERT INTO `mytable`.`attributes` (`attribute`, `intvalue`) VALUES ('brown-sequard', 1);
```

with the 'attribute' column being the sole primary key on the table results in...

```
Error Code: 1062 : Duplicate entry 'brown-sequard' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Futhermore, after issuing the first accented insert, doing a query on the un-accented version like:

```
select * from `mytable`.`attributes` where attribute='brown-sequard';
```

Will return the accented version 'brown-séquard.

How can I ensure that MySQL recognizes the difference between accented and unaccented characters with respect to primary key constraints?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried the solution found on this StackOverflow post:

[É vs. E in MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110295/vs-e-in-mysql-database?rq=1)

That is I added the parameters

```
&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

To my JDBC connection string.  This did not help :-(

**UPDATE 2**

I get the following interesting error code when I run the insert command with the accented "e" '(brown-séquard') from the command-line mysql client rather than the MySQL Workbench:

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\x82quard' for column 'attribute' at row 1
```

But I suspect that it has more to do with the windows command shell/CLI client choking on the accent encoding rather than the database connection itself.

Comment: http://dev.hubspot.com/blog/bid/7049/MySQL-and-Unicode-Three-Gotchas The last 'gotcha' might help. Perhaps your `character_set_client` is still set to `latin1`

Comment: Thanks, that makes quite a bit sense! My only remaining issue is that the article covers changing your "client character set" for the MySQL command prompt...  Is there a parallel setting/variable in JDBC?  I'm researching it as we speak but haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is related to character collation i.e. [the way MySQL compares characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collation-effect.html).

You can [use `COLLATE` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collate.html) in your query to enforce usage of specific collation for this one query, or change the column collation in table definition, to have it always one way or another.

Comment: Right on!

I changed schema create command from "CREATE SCHEMA my_schema CHARACTER SET utf8" to "CREATE SCHEMA my_schema CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin" and it now works like a charm.  I assume it would work if I did it using a more specific ALTER/CREATE TABLE command as well.

Thanks for the help!